# Curvature property like mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

For any $x,y \in S$ we have
$$f(y)=f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) + \frac{1}{2}(y-x)^T\nabla^2f(z)(y-x) $$

for some $z$ on the line segment $[x,y].$

I don't see why this should be true, other than that it 'feels' right.  Is there a simple proof?  Also, I'm not sure if the title is most appropriate, so feel free to edit it.

Comment: I'm assuming of course that the function is sufficiently smooth for second derivative to exist and be continuous.

Comment: This is just Taylor's theorem, with the remainder in a certain form. You can derive Taylor's theorem easily using integration by parts. Then use the mean value theorem for integration to get the remainder in the desired form. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/315412/35914

Comment: Cool... thanks!