# General formula for Taylor series for 3 and 4 variables with degree 3 polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

some time ago I was faced with a problem: I need to find the Taylor expansion with polynomial degree 3 for those two functions:
$$
f(x,y,z) = y^3\cos(xz^2) \\\text{and} \\
\\
f(x,y,z,w) = x^2yz+xyw^4.
$$
How can I do this? I know the general formula for 2 variables with degree 3, but I have no idea when we have 3 or 4 of them.

In this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834756/taylor-series-for-a-function-of-3-variables), there are some answers but I cant understand where to stop (they don't especificate the degree of polynomial).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Degree $3$ in each variable ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, in each one. This [link](http://www.math.brown.edu/tbanchof/howison/ma35labs-static-latest/38p1.html#:~:text=Taylor%20series%20are%20polynomials%20that,order%20approximation%20to%20the%20hypersurface.) has something helpful, but I cant know what to do with the third derivative. Thank you for your comment!